# Drug Dealer trigger priority

Tags: android-netrunner

When exactly does [`Drug Dealer`](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08083) trigger?

It says "When the corp's turn begins, draw 1 card."

When does that trigger on the corp's turn?

Does it trigger before the corp gets priority on turn 1.2?

---

Example:

The runner has 0 cards in hand at the end of the runners turn. The runner has [`Drug Dealer`](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08083) out. The corp has [`Bio Ethics Association`](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/10050) rezzed. Does the [`Bio Ethics Association`](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/10050) fire first and kill the runner or does the runner get to draw a card before taking net damage with [`Drug Dealer`](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08083)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both trigger at 1.2. Because it’s the corp’s turn, their card will activate first (see page 22, Simultaneous Effects), so the runner gets flatlined.

Comment: But the drug dealer says "when the corp's turn begins". Which does not fit the definition of what triggers during the 1.2 phase. 1.2 phase says "when your turn begins" conditionals trigger. Which would mean that is not part of those triggers.

Comment: You’re right, the wording is unfortunate. Still, that’s what is meant.

Comment: Bio Ethics Association is a corp card. "Your turn" on a corp card means corp's turn. It's as simple as that.

Comment: The actual definition of 1.2 (1.3 for runner) is 'turn begins' so all turn begins effects that trigger in this window trigger at the same time, starting with who's turn it is, be they each turn like [Corporate Sales Team](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/10037) your turn, like Bio Ethics Association, or opponents turn (referenced as corp for runner or runner for corp) like Drug Dealer.